# Limit of exponential function of the form $\infty/\infty$

Tags: limits

How would you solve for $$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{(e^\frac{1}{x}-1)}{(e^\frac{1}{x}+1)}$$

I tried to use the squeeze theorem, but this function doesn't have a definite range.

Comment: This limit only exists as one-sided limits -- there are different limits according whether $x$ approaches $0$ from above or from below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x=1/u$:

$$L=\lim_{|u|\to+\infty}\frac{e^u-1}{e^u+1}$$

We may now see that as $u\to-\infty$, then by direct substition, we get

$$L_-=\frac{0-1}{0+1}=-1$$

But as $u\to+\infty$, we get

$$L_+=\lim_{u\to+\infty}\frac{e^u-1}{e^u+1}=\lim_{u\to+\infty}\frac{e^u+1-2}{e^u+1}=\lim_{u\to+\infty}1-\frac2{e^u+1}=1-0=1$$

So the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

A more symmetric treatment, for the connoisseurs: Multiplying by $\frac12 e^{-1/2x}$ above and below the fraction bar gives us
$$ \frac{e^{1/x}-1}{e^{1/x}+1} =
\frac{\frac12(e^{1/2x}-e^{-1/2x})}{\frac12(e^{1/2x}+e^{-1/2x})} =
\frac{\sinh(1/2x)}{\cosh(1/2x)} = \tanh(1/2x) $$
and since $\tanh(u)$ has different limits for $u\to+\infty$ and $u\to-\infty$, the original limit does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\},\frac{e^\frac{1}{x}-1}{e^\frac{1}{x}+1}=1-\frac{2}{e^\frac{1}{x}+1}$$

Comment: I deleted my answer which was identical to your ! Same idea, same time. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici hahaha telepathy xD. Honors.

Comment: Good to know that you are in Marrakesh ! I was born in Dar el Beida, made all my studies in Rabat, started my career as assistant professor there, married a lady born in Rabat and so on !!

Comment: As @SimplyBeautifulArt has pointed, the limiting value is -1 as it approaches x from negatives. But, I'm still intrigued as to how you arrived at this beautiful manipulation.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Ah it's a honor for me to meet you here Professor! I was born in Marrakesh and I'm studying in FST Marrakesh as you saw in my profile, now on my third year.

Comment: @lPing7 SimplyBeautifulArt's answer is indeed simple. However, my answer doesn't contradict any thing. In fact, I didn't say that the limit is one. When $x\to 0^+$ you can see that the denominator goes to $+\infty$, getting $1$ as a limit, while when $x\to -\infty$, the denominator tends to $1$, getting $1-2=-1$ as a limit :). Thank you for your comment. Actually, this manipulation is a reflex you get when you study the [Partial Fraction Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition), a result useful for computing many integrals and sums.

Answer (score 1):

Just simplify they fraction.

$\displaystyle\frac{e^{1/x}-1}{e^{1/x}+1}=1-\frac{2}{e^{1/x}+1}$
then the answer is 1 if $x\to 0^+$
and when $x\to 0^-$ the answer is -1.

Therefore, the limit does not exist at x=0

Comment: Not when $x$ approaches $0$ from below!